# Link in jquery div stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

when i click on gallery, and visit for example "paintings", the links on the menu stops working, why is this? can someone please tell me whats wrong -_-

http://madebysam.se/elbarco

This is the code im using

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(){
      var aID = $(this).attr('href');
      var elem = $(''+aID).html();
      $('.target').html(elem);
      $('ul li').on('click',function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); })
    });
  });
```

Comment: The links work for me

Comment: Links are working for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Using dev tools and a breakpoint inside your example code snippet on your live site, I see that only the links loaded initially trigger your event handling code.

The problem is here:

```
$('a').on('click',function(){
   // do stuff
});
```

The common pitfall is that you register this handler against all anchor tags that are *loaded in the page at that moment*. Any anchor tags dynamically added later will not enjoy that same event handler.

A workaround is to use a different syntax, targeting first a larger tag that is guaranteed to be there on first load, and then filter down to the anchor tags:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
   // do stuff
});
```